# Not able to convert json data into csv in python while fetching data through api

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I read a string containing a json document.

```
d2 = json.loads(s1)
```

I am getting data in this format, a list of dictionnaries.

```py
[{'creati_id': 123,
  'creativ_id': 234,
  'status': 'adsc',
  'name': 'seded',
  …
  'video_75_views': None,
  'video_100_views': None,
  'estimated': None,
  'creative1': 1.0,
  'creative': 'Excellent',
  'value': 1.023424324}]}
```

How can I save this data in CSV format?

Comment: What did you end up with? What is the problem? First write row with your keys, then write values you get...

Comment: I am getting data in this format.

Comment: [{'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'}]},[{'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'}]},

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved with the csv module:

```py
import csv

data = [
    {
        "creati_id": 123,
        "creativ_id": 234,
        "status": "adsc",
        "name": "seded",
    }
]

with open("data_file.csv", "w") as data_file:

    csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file)

    header = data[0].keys()
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    for line in data:
        csv_writer.writerow(line.values())
```

Comment: I am getting data in this format

Comment: [{'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'}]},[{'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'}]}

Comment: The example you gave here is not valid.

Let say this is a list of dicts whose keys are always the same, my code will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard `csv` library in Python to write CSV files. From your question, I'm assuming that you have multiple rows, each having the structure you shared. If that's the case, then something like this should do the trick:

```
import csv

json1 = [
    {'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'},
    {'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'}
]

header_names = json1[0].keys()  # Extract the header names
data_rows = [row.values() for row in json1]  # Extract the values for each

with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header_names)  # Writes the header
    writer.writerows(data_rows)  # Writes the rows
```

Comment: [{'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'}]},[{'creati_id': 123, 'creativ_id': 234, 'status': 'adsc', 'name': 'seded', 'email': None, 'brand': 'adc', 'market': 'dcassca', 'channel': 'dAD'}]}

Comment: I've updated my answer to match your format